# Sorting Algorithm conundrum

Tags: sorting

I have been exposed to a lot of sorting algorithms lately: from bubble sort to radix and counting sort, but there is a particular problem for which I do not know what is legal to do or not.  (I'm still in the pseudo-code writing phase, so I am not yet writing the algs in code languages and running tests- thus my security about what is 'legal' and what is not, is kinda shaky.)

The problem is about sorting a list of intervals with respect to the start-point:
for example: sorting List1 = [[1,4] , [7, 17], [5, 10]] 
For the particular algorithm I've designed, I need them to be sorted into something like:
[[1,4] , [5, 10], [7, 17]]

I thought of doing radix sort backwards, but I read that radix sort is specifically for digits ordering. It does look like I could use bucket sort too, but we didn't learn about bucket sort in class...

Edit1: There is a time efficiency i need to worry about, so that's why I'm not doing the most straightforward solution and compare all List1[i][0] for i in range(list1)

Comment: ...why don't you just sort by the start point, and ignore the end point? Then you just sort the set of start points by any algorithm you know already.

Comment: well, yea, but i have to be careful with how much time it takes

Comment: I hope `"from bubble sort to radix and counting sort"` includes quick-sort and merge-sort.

Comment: Will you be sorting millions of intervals? If no, then you don't need to worry that much: any O(n log n) algorithm will be fine in pseudocode. (Practical implementation concerns demand that you use a nice algorithm like quick, intro, merge, or heap sort).

Comment: Unclear what you are asking about - any sorting algorithm can order sequences of elements if you provide comparison function. If you need to pick one throw a dice...

Comment: yes, it does. not quick-sort, but merge sort yes

Comment: oh really? Well, thanks a lot! :D i just needed to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the interval start points can be any real numbers, in that case I would advise you to use a **Comparison based sort** (insertion,selection,bubble,merge,heap,or quick) instead of Distribution sort (radix, counting or bucket). Though comparison based sorts have a lower bound of O(nlogn) but they can be used in any general case as compared to O(n) sorts like counting/ bucket which require input to be in some specific range.